# Avoid adding duplicate object in a list before adding a custom object to list?

Tags: c#

I red a few articles on internet but all value to me, I couldn't understand how can I avoid adding a duplicate object to a list, I tried something like this.

I actually have created a class which overrides GetHashCode and Equal method.

Now I want to form a collection of non duplicate object list.

```
public class FlightInfo
    {
        public string Origin { get; set; }

        public string DepartureTime { get; set; }

        public string Destination { get; set; }

        public string DestinationTime { get; set; }

        public string Price { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as FlightInfo;

            if (other == null)
                return false;

            if (Origin != other.Origin || DepartureTime != other.DepartureTime || Destination != other.Destination
                || DestinationTime != other.DestinationTime || Price != other.Price)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hashOrigin = Origin.GetHashCode();
            int hashDestination = Destination.GetHashCode();

            int hashDepartureTime = DepartureTime.GetHashCode();

            int hashDestinationTime = DestinationTime.GetHashCode();

            int hashPrice = Price.GetHashCode();

            return hashOrigin ^ hashDestination ^ hashDepartureTime ^ hashDestinationTime ^ hashPrice;
        }
    }
```

I also tried one article by Eric

```
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/
```

but this article has

```
private List<T>[] buckets = new List<T>[100];
```

insead of private `List<T>() buckets = new List<T>()`

but I want to return a list with no fix size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already implemented the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods you can have your own custom list of `FlightInfo` that will make use of those methods:

```
public class FlightInfoList : IList<FlightInfo>
{
    private readonly List<FlightInfo> _flightInfos = new List<FlightInfo>();

    public IEnumerator<FlightInfo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _flightInfos.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(FlightInfo item)
    {
        if (_flightInfos.Any(flightInfo => flightInfo.Equals(item)))
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot add duplicated values!");
        }

        _flightInfos.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _flightInfos.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(FlightInfo item)
    {
        return _flightInfos.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(FlightInfo[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _flightInfos.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(FlightInfo item)
    {
        return _flightInfos.Remove(item);
    }

    public int Count => _flightInfos.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public int IndexOf(FlightInfo item)
    {
        return _flightInfos.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, FlightInfo item)
    {
        _flightInfos.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _flightInfos.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public FlightInfo this[int index]
    {
        get => _flightInfos[index];
        set => _flightInfos[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Notice that in the `Add` method I'm checking if there's a duplicated. Another way to solve this is to use a dictionary.

Comment: How should i expose this object to external world, is it good to make this a public  _flightInfos.

Comment: No need for that! you can simply instance it like `var flightInfoes = new FlightInfoList();` and use it like this: `flightInfoes.Add(new FlightInfo());`. Notice that `FlightInfoList` implements the interface `IList<FlightInfo>` which makes it work like a list. The actual list of `FlightInfo`'s is hidden inside the object itself, the idea is to force the outside to use our custom `Add` method that checks for duplicates.

Comment: @javier-capelloan :Could you give me insight, how this becomes a list, just by **implementing Ilist<T>** a class becomes a list, if I had two hidden list objects then how would Iterate over both? they both will be availabe on class object?